# web Push notification using polymer and firebase with firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, google-cloud-functions, polymer-2.x

Hi I want to send web push notifications from my PWA created with polymer, I want to use firebase with firebase functions as a "backend", but Im lost, I have been searching in google but i cant find a good example to do that ¿do you know about a complete example using those tecnologies?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install **web-push** into your firebase function:
 `npm install web-push --save`

Then here is how to init the library and send a notification.

```
const webpush = require('web-push');

// VAPID keys should only be generated only once.
const vapidKeys = webpush.generateVAPIDKeys();

webpush.setGCMAPIKey('<Your GCM API Key Here>');
webpush.setVapidDetails(
  'mailto:example@yourdomain.org',
  vapidKeys.publicKey,
  vapidKeys.privateKey
);

// This is the same output of calling JSON.stringify on a PushSubscription
const pushSubscription = {
  endpoint: '.....',
  keys: {
    auth: '.....',
    p256dh: '.....'
  }
};

webpush.sendNotification(pushSubscription, 'Your Push Payload Text');
```

reference: https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push

Detailed tutorial to setup web-push [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1vd6cFL0Vg3-ciDq2xpN0HxN_UowyKjJsTrCOdulkExM/edit):